# Not able to calculate this expectation

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, variance

If $h_{1}, h_{2}, \dots, h_{N}$ are zero mean i.i.d Gaussian random variables with variance $\sigma_{h}^{2}$, then how do I calculate the value of

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(h_{1}^{2} + h_{2}^{2} + \dots, h_{N}^{2} \right)^{2}\right]$$

The only clue I have is that

$$\mathbb{E}\left[h_{i}^{2}\right] = \sigma_{h}^{2}$$

I do not know how to compute $\mathbb{E}\left[h_{i}^{2} h_{j}^{2}\right]$ (for all $i \neq j$). Please help.

Comment: Yes, they are independent. Apologies for the ambiguity. Have corrected the question

Comment: I expected that....already answered. $\sigma_h^2$ is constant right? thus I used simply $\sigma^2$

Comment: Yes, variance is constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Y=h_1^2+\dots + h_N^2 =\sigma^2\left[\left(\frac{h_1}{\sigma}\right)^2+\dots+\left(\frac{h_N}{\sigma}\right)^2 \right]$$

It is self evident that

$$Y\sim Gamma\left(\frac{N}{2};\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

Thus its second moment is

$$\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=\mathbb{V}[Y]+\mathbb{E}^2[Y]=\frac{N}{2}4\sigma^4+\left(\frac{N}{2}2\sigma^2\right)^2=(N+2)N\sigma^4$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I have a follow-up question - is it possible to compute the value of $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(h_{1}h_{2} + h_{2}h_{3} + \dots, h_{N-1}h_{N} \right)^{2}\right]$? Will it be zero?

Comment: @MaxFrost:  with a simply calculation by mind, I get $(N-1)\sigma^4$...I hope I did not do some errors...but it looks fine to me

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the follow-up question in the comments

When  you expand the square you will have a matrix of $(N-1)\times(N-1)$ elements.

The $N-1$ elements in the principal diagonal are in the form $E(h_i^2h_{i+1}^2)=\sigma^4$

All the other elements contains at least on element  $E(h_i)=0$ thus they are all zero.

Thus the result is $(N-1)\sigma^4$

Comment: Hi! Thanks again for answering! Actually I just realized I am supposed to compute $\mathbb{E}\left[|h_{1}^{*}h_{2} + h_{2}^{*}h_{3} + \dots, h_{N-1}^{*}h_{N}|^{2}\right]$ (assuming all random variables are complex)? Will it be same as above? Shall I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: @MaxFrost better it is to ask it in a separate question.